# MVC3 httpPost method not loading view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have a form whose front page loads up correctly, but whenever I try to submit, I get the following error:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Search/DoSearch
```

I have an MVC 3 form with the following control

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(FormModel formModel)
        {

            return View("Thanks", formModel);
        }

    }
```

the Index page has the form

```
@model RequestForm.Models.FormModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="@Href("~/Content/Site.css")" type="text/css"/>
<title>Request page</title>
</head>
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-class" })){
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.fullName,"Full Name")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.fullName)


      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.address, "Address")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.address)

      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.phone, "Phone Number")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.phone)

      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.email,"Email")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.email)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a thanks view page

```
@model RequestForm.Models.FormModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Thanks</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Thank you for your submission
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

why is the thanks view page not being called upon and why does the requested URL search/Dosearch?

Comment: You specified the URL with `Html.BeginForm("DoSearch", "Search",...` which means Action : "DoSearch" controller: "Search" which point to the url `/Search/DoSearch` I think you meant: `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is being posted to the `DoSearch` action method of `Search` controller. You need to change the Form declaration part in your view to fix that. Change it to `Index` action method of `HomeController`.

In your view,
change this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-class" })){
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-class" })){
```

If you don't want to give the class attribute to your form, you can simplify the above like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  // form elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the submit handler not defined at the controller side,

If you are submitting with the target parameters shown, you need to have an action method DoSearch in controller, SearchController , otherwise you need to submit to the Index action method in home controller by changing the form target parameters as

```
HTML.BeginForm("Index","Home")
```